# Showing a listview with Hashmap data

Tags: android, eclipse, listview, hashmap, android-arrayadapter

im in trouble.

I have one HashMap what i need to be a global variable ( accesible for more than one activity). This hashmap has a list of contacts which key is its mail address... so i have pairs email address, full contact data. Here is my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    miAgenda= new HashMap<String, contactoAgenda>();
    contactoAgenda Eduardo = new contactoAgenda("Eduardo", "c/ Segovia","973", "edufissure@msn.com",true, true, false, false, true,"Laboral");
    miAgenda.put(Eduardo.getMail(),Eduardo);

    contactoAgenda Daniel= new contactoAgenda("Daniel", "c/ Diego Madrazo","92458", "dani@msn.com",true, true, false, false, true,"Familia");
    miAgenda.put(Daniel.getMail(),Daniel);

    contactoAgenda Belen= new contactoAgenda("Belen", "c/ Diego Madrazo","92458", "belen@gmail.com",true, true, false, false, true,"Familia");
    miAgenda.put(Belen.getMail(),Belen);


      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hola"+miAgenda.size()+"\n" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

      ListView lista=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listaContactos);
         ArrayAdapter<contactoAgenda> adaptador = new ArrayAdapter<contactoAgenda>(this,R.id.editText1, (List<contactoAgenda>) miAgenda.get(contactoAgenda);
         lista.setAdapter(adaptador);
```

The trouble is that i need to show the ListView lista with all the contacts... and i got stuck on making the adapter.... I cant find any similar example with a Hashmap made by a field of an object ( mail of contactoAgenda, and the own object all the contactoagenda with all the files...

Any help would be apreciated. Im using api 15.An im a noobie here.

thanks in advance

Comment: Just FYI: having a global HashMap is a bad idea. Instead, consider having a content provider. As a matter of fact, Android provides immediately a ContactsProviders out of the box, which looks like something you might want.

Comment: Well i need a custom contactoAgenda which i have to store in a array...not related to contactsProvider...Thanks for your response...

Answer (score 0):

You can just convert your `Map` to an `ArrayList`

```
ArrayAdapter<contactoAgenda> adaptador = new ArrayAdapter<contactoAgenda>(this,R.id.editText1, miAgenda.values();
```

Note, the `ArrayAdapter` won't know how to properly display the `contactoAgenda` class type. You can can override it's `toString()` method which will control how it's displayed to the screen. More appropriately would be to implement your on custom adapter with the a `getView()` implementation that can handle the `contactoAgenda` class type.

Comment: Could you be more explicit please and make an example ? I also have the toSTring method done in contactoAgenda. Now i dont know how to populate the listview with all contacts and display for example name and email or name and phone ( display two fielsds in every item of the listview).

Comment: By the way... it gives me error the instruction you gave me...seems hashmap doesnt allow miagenda.values...and seems it misses a ). Although it gives error....